# Create a new variable to epidemiological week

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column week and another year (87 weeks). I need to create a new column (weekseq) with a number that identify the week sequentially from first to last. I dont know how to do. Someone can help me?

Example:

id  week    month   year    yearweek    weekseq

1   1   1   2014    2014/1
1   1   1   2013    2013/1
1   2   1   2014    2014/2
1   2   1   2013    2013/2
1   3   1   2014    2014/3
1   3   1   2013    2013/3
1   4   1   2014    2014/4
1   4   1   2013    2013/4
1   5   1   2014    2014/5
1   5   1   2013    2013/5
1   6   2   2014    2014/6
1   6   2   2013    2013/6
1   7   2   2014    2014/7
1   7   2   2013    2013/7
1   8   2   2014    2014/8
1   8   2   2013    2013/8
1   9   2   2014    2014/9
1   9   2   2013    2013/9
1   10  3   2014    2014/10 
1   10  3   2013    2013/10 
1   11  3   2014    2014/11 
1   11  3   2013    2013/11 
1   12  3   2014    2014/12 
1   12  3   2013    2013/12

Comment: It would be better if you show few lines of your dataset in your post

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and also the SO guidelines for asking a new question

Comment: Without an example, it is difficult to comment. Perhaps, you can try `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, seqCol:= as.numeric(factor(week)), year][]` or `setDT(df)[, seqCol:= rleid(week), year][]`

Comment: Could you show the expected result as well?

Comment: If `ID` is the expected output column `setDT(df)[,ID:= 1:.N , list(week, year)][]`

Comment: Might be good to note that `rleid()` is only in the 1.9.5 dev version of data.table

Comment: @akrun I  hope the variable weekyear  like this week year weekseq
49 2012 1
50 2012 2
51 2012 3
52 2012 4
1 2013 5
2 2013 6
3 2013 7

Comment: @RIchardScriven Thanks, but I guess the OP's expected output is not clear.

Comment: @DanielleAndreza The new data on the comment looks different than the posted one and the sequence you showed is not grouping on `year`.  So simply, `df$weekseq <- 1:nrow(df)`

Comment: @DanielleAndreza  What is the expected `weekseq` based on the new data?

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires the 'dplyr' and 'plyr' packages:

```
# Coerce into tbd_df
datatbl <- tbl_df(data)

# Arrange, giving more weight to year than week
datatbl <- arrange(datatbl, year, month, week)

# Create a new column that numbers the arranged rows sequentially
seqtbl <- ddply(datatbl, .(id), transform, sequence=seq_along(id))
```

Comment: @Chistopher Hersh,                                                                           The problem is that each week is repeated about 700 times, because that is the number of traps that are inspected weekly. When I use the weeks following code will 1-61051 (the total lines), and the right would be from 1 to 87. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I've added the month variable to the `arrange()` function so that each `id` will be arranged most heavily by `year`, then `month`, then `week`.

The last step was changed based on your description to only number sequentially within each `id`. Now it will split the data set up into individual `id` groupings after they've been arranged, then apply the `seq_along()` function before combining everything back into the tbl_df `seqtbl`.